# Django : donwloading server files on client side

Tags: django, django-templates

I am running a Django project on a company server also that stores some .pdf and .docx files.
Only workers have acces to this Django app throught their local machines and they need to download files from the server to their machines.
I used webbrowser open, but files were opened on server machine in stead of clients one.
Can you please help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they files in your static folder in django? If they are you should be able to just link to them.. <a href="/static/file" download>download</a>. Otherwise, you can make a view that loads the file from another place, and returns it? https://zetcode.com/django/fileresponse/

Comment: No, they aren't. Another process is downloading those files on other path and I must take the files from that path.

Comment: Ah ok. I've done the same thing before. We used the `requests` library to save the files into a temp folder on the server, and then use a django view (like already linked) to server back the downloaded files.